Tikz \draw angle and length leads to strange results
Why is the angle:length argument in draw leading to strange results after the second point?
\documentclass{article}

\include{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw  (0,0) -- (-45:1) -- (90:1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

I have tried several values instead of the 90 but neither leads to a result I understand. Even using 0 leads to a strange angle...

Can you please add a screenshot? As it stands it starts at the origin, moves to (1.4, -1.4) and then to (0,1), if you translate polar into cartesian. Did you mean relative moves with + or ++?

Why do you use \include{tikz}?

@MS-SPO: Thank you. That was my mistake. I assumed it to be relative, but of course it was not as I forgot the ++. My earlier solution worked with cartesian coordinates I got confused in the change. Thanks!

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Is it not necessary?

The fact that \include{tikz} does not give an error is due to a bizarre series of accidental code paths.  never use \include in the preamble and never to include code, it is for optional inclusion of chapters of text.  use \usepackage{tikz]

It does produce LaTeX Warning: \include should only be used after \begin{document} on input line 3. unless you are using an old latex.

@mrCarnivore Can you make a sketch how you think the drawing should look like? The curve I get seems to be in agreement with the instructions in your code.

You are right. I was using other languages lately and forgot it is \usepackage instead of \inlcude in latex...

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz: Yes. I was under the false assumption it was relative and not absolute. using ++ is the solution that make the code work the way I intended.

I’m voting to close this question because it seems that it was solved in comments.

I am placing an answer from the comments as an official answer:
the code line \draw  (0,0) -- (-45:1) -- (90:1); draws a line from (0,0) to (-45:1). This part works. The next line is then drawn from that point to (90:1) but that coordinate is not relative because no ++ was used before the brackets. Therefore it does not create a 90° angle to the last line of from the last point, but rather a 90° angle from (0,0).
To use relative coordinates use ++ and therefore:
\draw  (0,0) -- (-45:1) -- ++(90:1);
